# Extracting array value from nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

Hi guys i have created the following array of objects . And to be honest i am a little bit lost . But please take a look and help me out

```
[
          {
        name: "bananaLight",
        bananaDefinition: [
            {
                bananaRef: 'startBanana',
                title: 'Start Banana'
            },
            { 
                bananaRef: 'endBanana',
                title: 'End Banana'
            }
           ]
          },
          {
        name: "bananaFull",
        bananaDefinition: [
            {
                bananaRef: 'bananaSize'
                title: 'Banana Size'
            },
            {
                bananaRef: 'startBanana',
                title: 'Start Banana'
            },
            { 
                bananaRef: 'endBanana',
                title: 'End Banana'
            }
           ]
         }
]
```

The idea here is to fetch the array of `bananaDefinition` bounded with the name `bananaLight`

Comment: there's no `bananaLight` in your array/object, but if your map returns `bananaDefinition` you'll have an array of arrays by specs.

Comment: `const result = bananaArray.find(v => v.name === 'bananaLight')`

Comment: @AndreaGiammarchi ok so how to return the full array sitting together with `bananaLight`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen the `find` method returns me only a `boolean` nothing else

Comment: No it doesn't. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
const bananaArray = [{
  name: "bananaLight",
  bananaDefinition: [{
    bananaRef: 'startBanana',
    title: 'Start Banana'
  }, {
    bananaRef: 'endBanana',
    title: 'End Banana'
  }]
}, {
  name: "bananaFull",
  bananaDefinition: [{
    bananaRef: 'bananaSize',
    title: 'Banana Size'
  }, {
    bananaRef: 'startBanana',
    title: 'Start Banana'
  }, {
    bananaRef: 'endBanana',
    title: 'End Banana'
  }]
}];

const result = bananaArray.find(v => v.name === 'bananaLight').bananaDefinition;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yes , you were right it does not return a `boolean` . Sorry it was my mistake . Thanks mate for the help . This is exactly what i've needed

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you want to do you might want to get it from different ways. here is some of them:

```
const dataArray = [
  {
    name: "bananaLight",
    bananaDefinition: [
      {
        bananaRef: "startBanana",
        title: "Start Banana",
      },
      {
        bananaRef: "endBanana",
        title: "End Banana",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "bananaFull",
    bananaDefinition: [
      {
        bananaRef: "bananaSize",
        title: "Banana Size",
      },
      {
        bananaRef: "startBanana",
        title: "Start Banana",
      },
      {
        bananaRef: "endBanana",
        title: "End Banana",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

`1`

```
const bananaLightFind = dataArray.find((item) => item.name === "bananaLight");
```

`2`

```
const foundIndex = dataArray.findIndex(item => item.name === "bananaLight")
const bananaLightFindIndex = dataArray[foundIndex];
```

`3`

```
let bananaLightLoop;
dataArray.forEach((item) => {
  if (item.name === "bananaLight") {
    bananaLightLoop = item;
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes mate . It seems that there is multiple way to go with it . Thanks for you effort and your examples . Now for me is more clear what i have to do .